# Is it possible to use a formula within the conditional expression of SUMIF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say I have the following column: 100, 123, 400, 64
I want to use SUMIF to sum up all numbers that divide by 100 with no reminder. That is, I want the result to be 500, for the above example. I need to somehow use MOD(?,100)=0 conditional expression.
My question is more general whether it is possible to use functions in SUMIF (or COUNTIF etc.) conditional expression.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. It is what we give up to allow it to be optimized(Non-Array).

But you can use SUMPRODUCT:

For the SUM:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(A1:A4,100)=0)* A1:A4)
```

For the COUNT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(A1:A4,100)=0))
```

`(MOD(A1:A4,100)=0)` will return TRUE/FALSE as it iterates through the array.  By using mathematical operands on it, the TRUE/FALSE becomes 1/0 respectively.  so the SUMPRODUCT does the math and adds the resulting array together.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While accepting [Scott Craner](https://superuser.com/users/567231/scott-craner)'s answer is correct and is probably the one you will want to use, I thought you might be interested to know that `SUMIF()` *can* be used in this specific instance.

Since `SUMIF()` supports regular expressions, you can use the following:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A4,"^.*00$")
```

This works because the numbers in `A1:A4` are implicitly converted to text for the regular expression match, which looks for strings ending in two zeroes (if whole string matching is enabled, `^` and `$` can be omitted).

The method can be generalised for numbers which are multiples of powers of 10, or powers of 10 with a specific remainder, but Scott's answer can be used for multiples of any number and for many other criteria.

Note: I tested this with LibreOffice Calc, since I don't have easy access to a recent release of Excel, but I have found functions to be pretty compatible between them. Regular Expressions (and whole string matching) are enabled by default in Calc, but they may need to be set in Excel.

Update: Scott now informs me that RE are not supported in `SUMIF()` criteria, but I'll leave the answer for the benefit of LibreOffice users.

Comment: Does not work in Excel.

Comment: @ScottCraner - It didn't work in an early release, but I guessed (erroneously, it seems) that it might have been added since then.

Comment: Nope, still no love on the RegEx line.

Comment: @ScottCraner - That's a shame: I'll leave the answer for academic interest to LibreOffice users.